# K-Means model always predicts the same class after saving and loading

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have created K-Means clustering model with Python and Sklearn.
Now I want to save the model and vectoriser so that I can make predictios.

This is my model:

```
# Vectoriser - CountVectorizer
transformerVectoriser = CountVectorizer(analyzer = 'word', ngram_range = (1, 4), vocabulary = vocab_list)
vectorized_features = transformerVectoriser.fit_transform(features)

# PCA - TruncatedSVD
pca = TruncatedSVD(n_components = 2, random_state = None)
vec_matrix_pca = pca.fit_transform(vectorized_features)

# Clustering Model
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters = 100, max_iter = 1500, init = 'k-means++', random_state = None)
kmeans.fit(vec_matrix_pca)
```

My question is, what I need to save and how?
I know that I need to save the model (how?), but should I also save `transformerVectoriser` (how?) and `pca` (how?) ?
Also, when I call/load the model, should I do `fit_transform` for `transformerVectoriser` and `pca`, or only `transform`?

The issue that I have that after saving and loading all 3 things (model and 2 vectorisers) my model always predicts only 1 cluster.

I got `silhouette_score` of 0.6 for number of 100 clusters.

I have saved like this:

```
model_filename = 'kmeans_clustering_recommender_model.pkl'
pickle.dump(kmeans, open(model_filename, 'wb'))

vectorizer_filename = 'kmeans_clustering_recommender_vectoriser.pkl'
pickle.dump(transformerVectoriser, open(vectorizer_filename, 'wb'))

pca_filename = 'kmeans_clustering_recommender_PCA.pkl'
pickle.dump(pca, open(pca_filename, 'wb'))
```

This is how I make prediction:

```
model = pickle.load(open("kmeans_clustering_recommender_model.pkl", 'rb'))
vectorizer = pickle.load(open("kmeans_clustering_recommender_vectoriser.pkl", 'rb'))
pca = pickle.load(open("kmeans_clustering_recommender_PCA.pkl", 'rb'))


def preprocessing(news_body):
    
    
    # Simple text preprocessing
    text = news_body.lower().strip()
              
    vectorized_text = vectorizer.transform([text])
    vectorized_text_pca = pca.transform(vectorized_text)
    
    return vectorized_text_pca

text = "SAMPLE TEXT FOR CLUSTERING"

preprocessed_text = preprocessing(news_body)
result = model.predict(preprocessed_text)
print(result) # I am always getting the same number
```

I have only 7 clusters (out of 100) that has less than 20 datapoints, 80% of clusters has between 50 and 300 datapoints.

This is how it looks on the graph:

[image]

The thing is, I have tried with other algorithm, such as `GaussianMixture`, and still, I am getting the same class, and when I do this, before saving and loading the model:

```
kmeans.labels_
```

Everything works good

Comment: Check out Scikit-learn's [model persistence guide](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/model_persistence.html). It has some key points.

Comment: I have read it, but it was not helpful.

Comment: Did you check how much predictions fall in each cluster in your training set? Is it the same after you save the pickle model?

Comment: I have only 7 clusters (out of 100) that has less than 20 datapoints, 80% of clusters has between 50 and 300 datapoints

Answer (score -1):

You can save and then load a model (or any serializable object) using `pickle` library:

```
import pickle

filename = "kmeans.pickle"

pickle.dump(kmeans, open(filename, "wb"))
loaded_kmeans = pickle.load(open(filename, "rb"))
```

Comment: What should I save?